# Setting up new Red5 server runtime in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, red5

Tried to setup Red5 project in Eclipse. When I tried to create a new server runtime for Red5, I got an error saying `red5.jar` is not found.

This file isn't available anywhere where I installed Red5. I could find `red5-client-1.0.jar` and `red5-server-1.0.jar` only.

[image]

Is the plugin outdated? or I am searching for red5.jar in the wrong place?

Tutorial - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EedQyafOIm0

Comment: I am having the same problem. It is as if the Red5 plugin is not in sync with the Red5 server version...  It would be nice if someone from Infrared5 was to look at this. It appears to me that there is a bug in the plugin or in the distribution...

Comment: I just encountered this problem as well

Comment: Because of this error, I gave up my thought on using red5

Comment: I never used with this runtime configuration, but i think it will work if you rename the file red5-server-1.0.jar to red5.jar

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can remove server runtime and add red5-server.jar to build path for compile time. I did it before and it works for me.